# Update query string parameter from admin javascript

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, parse-platform

I am trying to make an admin panel and I have to edit user's details (parse.com) from this panel. 
After many searches on google I succeded to display the user's firstname and lastname. I made another function with query.first() but I can edit only the first user, what should I do to can edit second user or third ? 
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/parse-1.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="demo">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="adminPannel">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody><tr ng-repeat="user in users">
                    <td><button class="btn" ng-click="editUser()"></button><input type="text" id="frstName" ng-value="Firstname" ng-model="firstNameCh"/><input type="text" id="lstName" ng-value="Lastname" ng-model="lastNameCh"/></td>
                    <td>{{ user.firstname }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.lastname }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and js:

```
var app=angular.module('demo',[]);
app.controller('adminPannel',['$scope',function($scope) {
$scope.users=[];

Parse.initialize("WnaPPAytzCE8AR7NNGENpVGMGQ6pQ9wH2LKRQ6wE", "2qfXZunNrQPnCgNuusPpbGCDmbRBzo7CG4X0edDF");
$scope.use=Parse.User.current();
var noname2=Parse.Object.extend("noname2");
var query=new Parse.Query(noname2);
//query.equalTo("uname",$scope.use.get('username'));
query.find({
  success:function(results) {
  alert("success");
  alert(results.length);
  for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++)
   {
     var object= results[i];

     $scope.users.push({'firstname':object.get('firstname') , 'lastname':object.get('lastname') ,'age':object.get('age')});

   }
    $scope.$apply();
 },
 error:function(error) {
  alert("error:"+ error.code +" "+error.message);
   }
});
$scope.editUser = function(){
  var query = new Parse.Query(noname2);
  query.first({
    success:function(noname2){
      noname2.save(null,{
        success:function(nm2){
          nm2.set('firstname', $('#frstName').val());
          nm2.set('lastname', $('#lstName').val());
          nm2.save();
          location.reload();
        }
      });
    },
    error:function(error){
      alert('error' + error.code + ' ' + error.message);
    }
  });
}
}]);
```

I don't know what should I change in my editUser function.

Answer (score 0):

Try here: https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Query.html

You can use `query.find` instead of `query.first` and then on success you'll get a results list of objects.

Comment: I thought query.find() doesn't have set() or save(). Should I add another query.find() after the first query.find(). Thanks

Comment: I can't test this myself at the moment but just try save and set from inside the find

Comment: I replaced the query.first with query.find. Console error: TypeError: noname2.save is not a function

Comment: You have to loop through the items now, instead of a single item you should've gotten an array of items. Try inspecting the returned object in debug.

Comment: I made that changes, something has changed :D but there is something wrong, I mean now fi I insert some text in first input, all details will be changed not only for the current user. I putted the code here to see how it works, you have to refresh the page to see the changes: http://plnkr.co/edit/jJj9RHT6GV1MEAVIDqcX?p=preview